# Allow the search engines to index documents, but only allowed access to paid members. Possible?

Tags: php, seo, web-crawler, document

I'm creating a website that will have the admin upload documents available only to the paid members of the website. But what I do want is that the search engines crawls or indexes the document, so that it appears in the search engine search results. Documents include DOC, DOCX and PDF.

For example i have a document that has this text: "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog". Now someone Google's "brown fox". Assuming that I have the standings, I would want the result to appear in the Google results. When the user clicks on it, I want that the user lands on a page, instead of the document, where there is a preview of the text with a link to be a member to view full document.

I planned that the preview of the document on the page will be saved into the database when the document is uploaded. So it is easily visible and crawl-able. For the full document, I could only figure to allow the full document to be crawled. But I think if I allow the search engine to crawl, then I'll be giving access to the users aswell. And if I use htaccess to keep the documents from being accessed directly then I'm shutting the crawlers out too.

I also considered extracting all document text and putting it in the database, but I read somewhere that it is very difficult to distinguish between a user and a spider, and using user agents is a bad idea as it is very easy to spoof.

So I'm confused as to how I should go about this. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not possible. Any user can pretend to be a search engine by changing their User-Agent.

You could do IP-address-based restrictions, or heuristic-based detection, but you're likely to accidentally block crawlers.

Perhaps you should give users a number of free page views per day, or consider a different method of monetization.

Comment: Thank you! The free views sparked my attention. I will try something along those lines

Comment: If users go to your page from a search engine expecting the content they found in a search engine, they certainly will not stick around on your site if that content is no longer available because you're over the number of allotted page views for the day.  Protect your content in this way if you must, but I don't think this will be a viable business model for you.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is allow an index of your page, complete with relevant content snippets, visible to the public.

Don't try to fool search engines by giving specific content to their user agent.  Users can easily get around that, even by simply using search engine features for caching and what not.  Experts Exchange is notorious for this.  These kinds of tricks are not worth your time.

In short, be honest with your page.  Display some for everyone, and only allow those with accounts to get to the full content, if you must.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I had planned already, but now I feel confident about it.